# TypeScript compiler in WebStorm see TSConfig.json as a Typescript file

Tags: typescript, webstorm, tsconfig

In my TypeScript project in WebStorm if I use TypeScript compiler using `tsconfig.json`, the compiler sees this file as a TS file.

**TypeScript Settings in WebStorm:**
[image: TypeScript Settings in WebStorm]

**Error:**
[image]

If I change the Settings to "Set Options Manually", the compiler works perfect.

How can I fix that compiler sees tsconfig.json as a config file?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings -> Editor -> File Types -> TypeScript` and remove any form of `tsconfig.json` from the `Registered Patterns`.

Comment: In TypeSript I have only *.ats and *.ts as registered patterns!

Answer (score 0):

It's a [problem with WebStorm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22833) and it's fixed in v2016.3

For now, JetBrains suggest disabling 'Use typescript service (experimental)' option - this issue seems to only occur when this service is enabled